# How can i write a part of string in Integer.toString

Tags: android, integer

I found this code to create a battery widget:

```
public class BatteryStatusWidgetActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {  
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
      private String batteryLevel = "init";  
      private int widgetImageFrame = R.drawable.widget_batt_frame01;  
      @Override  
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
           context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));  
           updateView(context);  
      }  
      @Override  
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
           int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);  
           int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);  
           int level = 65;  
           level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;  
           String batteryLevel = level + "%";  
           widgetImageFrame = R.drawable.widget_batt_frame01;  
           updateView(context);  
           super.onReceive(context, intent);  
      }  
      public void updateView(Context context) {  
           RemoteViews thisViews = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);  
           thisViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, batteryLevel);  
           thisViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView1, widgetImageFrame);  
           ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, BatteryStatusWidgetActivity.class);  
           AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, thisViews);  
      }
```

This will display in the widget only the number of battery level. I mean "65" and i want display "65%". But if i try to write something like `batteryLevel = Integer.toString(level+"%");` i get error.. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace your code in `onReceive()` to the following,

```
 @Override  
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
           int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);  
           int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);  
           int level = -1;  
           level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;  
           batteryLevel = level+"%"; 
           widgetImageFrame = R.drawable.widget_batt_frame01;  
           updateView(context);  
           super.onReceive(context, intent);  
      }
```

The basic reason you get an error for `Integer.toString(level+"%")` is `Integer.toString()` method used here accepts an `int` value but not a `String` value. `level+"%"` is a String value

Answer (score 2):

```
int level = 65;
String batteryLevel = level + "%";
```

Comment: the 65 was and example..could be 55,80,90.. is the current battery level..so i don't think it's correct in this way..level is a variable that change when battery change.

Comment: Yeah I got that, the int level = 65; is just an example.
replace your "batteryLevel = Integer.toString(level);" with "batteryLevel = level + "%";"

that should do the trick.

Comment: You already declared the "batteryLevel" String, so don't do it again. I think you should read a good book about Java.

Comment: I agree with @Pewiity. Concatenating an int to a String is among the first few things you usually learn when starting java.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will work

`int level= 65;

String batterylevel = String.valueOf(level)+"%";`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
int level = -1
level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;  
String batteryLevel = level + "%";
```